# Evaluate datetime.date column with NoneType

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, comparison-operators

I have a pandas column, created from a pd.read-sql query.  There are null dates in the column and they are returned as NoneTypes that looks like the following.

```
FFD
2014-10-29
2015-06-03
None
2017-05-05


print(type(stores['FFD'][0]))
class datetime.date
print(type(stores['FFD'][2]))
class'NoneType'
```

I then try to run the following function:

```
sixty = now - timedelta(60)
def f(row):
    if row['FFD'] < sixty:
        val = 'SR'
    return val

stores['JRSR'] = stores.apply(f, axis = 1)
```

This returns an error :

```
TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.date'", 'occurred at index 10')
```

I am able to convert the column to string, for comparison purposes, however I need this field to remain as a date field for downstream uses.  My conversion code is:

```
stores['FFD'] = pd.to_datetime(stores['FFD'])
stores['FFD'] = stores['FFD'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

How can I get my function to work without converting the column?  Essentially I want my function to evaluate ONLY the datetime.date objects.  I tried:

```
def(f)row:
    if isinstance(row['FFD'], NoneType):
         val = ""
    elif row['FFD'] < sixty:
         val = 'SR'
```

But that did not work as intended.

Comment: In your first function, changing `if row['FFD'] < sixty:` to `if row['FFD']  and row['FFD'] < sixty:` might help. And in the second version of your function, the function header has a typo. Change `(f)row` to `f(row)`.

Comment: wow - how simple.  Just adding the and from your first suggestion worked perfectly.  What does if row['FFD'] and...do?

Comment: oh yea, and Thank you !!!

Comment: Jason, I have added the explanation for `if row['FFD']` in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In the first `f` function, changing

`if row['FFD'] < sixty:`

to

`if row['FFD'] and row['FFD'] < sixty:`

solved OP's issue.

`if row['FFD']` will evaluate to `True`if `row['FFD']` contains anything else than `NoneType`, `0` or `False`. This is the Pythonic way to check for presence of `None`. Note that because of the short-circuit behaviour of logical operators, check for `None` should always be placed first in a compound condition. So `if row['FFD'] and row['FFD'] < sixty:` will work, but `if row['FFD'] < sixty and if row['FFD']` won't.